# Hiding/showing of columns with external filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using ui-grid with external filtering enabled. I have registered the handlers for:

```
            gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, getFilters);

            gridApi.core.on.columnVisibilityChanged($scope, function (column) {
                column.filters[0].term = null;
                ctrl.gridApi.core.raise.filterChanged();
            });
```

The problem I see is that when I type something in the filtering input box, the filtering works as expected and I get a subset of results. Now I go ahead and try to hide the filtering column, with filtering term still there. What I want is to reset that filter which I attempt to do in columnVisibilityChanged listening callback. I see all the callbacks fire but when I get the data back the hidden column gets re-added back into the grid. My external filtering repopulates the grid.data array and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth here is how I was able to get around this issue:

```
                gridApi.core.on.columnVisibilityChanged($scope, function (column) {
                    // must find a column on the appScope and set its visibility property
                    _.forEach(ctrl.gridApi.grid.appScope.columns, function(appScopeColumn){
                        // find filterable column
                        if (column.enableFiltering && column.field === appScopeColumn.id) {
                            appScopeColumn.visible = column.visible;
                            // only trigger filterChanged event if the column's filter was set
                            if(column.filters[0].term) {
                                ctrl.gridApi.core.raise.filterChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                });
```